# Get array_agg to filter duplicates based on another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to make a request that can be expressed in terms of books and authors as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE author (id BIGSERIAL UNIQUE NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE book (id BIGSERIAL UNIQUE NOT NULL, title TEXT NOT NULL, author_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES author(id));
CREATE TABLE fan (id BIGSERIAL UNIQUE NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL, book_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES book(id));

experiments=# SELECT * FROM author;
 id |        name
----+--------------------
  2 | Johnathan Williams
  3 | Lewis Carroll
  4 | Guy Fox
(3 rows)

experiments=# SELECT * FROM book;
 id |        title        | author_id
----+---------------------+-----------
  1 | Fairy tales         |         2
  2 | Alice in Wonderland |         3
  3 | Some other book     |         4
  4 | The final book      |         3
  5 | Some other book     |         4
(5 rows)

experiments=# SELECT * FROM fan;
 id | name  | book_id
----+-------+---------
  1 | Alex  |       1
  2 | Alice |       2
  3 | Jimmy |       3
  4 | James |       4
  5 | Nate  |       3
  6 | Mary  |       2
  7 | Alex  |       1
  8 | Mary  |       2
(8 rows)
```

To recreate the database you can use the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE author (id BIGSERIAL UNIQUE NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE book (id BIGSERIAL UNIQUE NOT NULL, title TEXT NOT NULL, author_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES author(id));
CREATE TABLE fan (id BIGSERIAL UNIQUE NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL, book_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES book(id));
INSERT INTO author (name, id) VALUES ('Johnathan Williams', 2), ('Lewis Carroll', 3), ('Guy Fox', 4);
INSERT INTO book (title, author_id) VALUES ('Fairy tales', 2), ('Alice in Wonderland', 3), ('Some other book', 4), ('The final book', 3), ('Some other book', 4);
INSERT INTO fan (name, book_id) VALUES ('Alex', 1), ('Alice', 2), ('Jimmy', 3), ('James', 4), ('Nate', 3), ('Mary', 2);
INSERT INTO fan (name, book_id) VALUES ('Alex', 1), ('Mary', 2);
```

Now, I need authors together with arrays of their book titles and their fans. This is what I do

```
 SELECT
  (SELECT array_agg(author.name))[1] AS author_name,
  author.id AS author_id,
  array_agg(fan.name ORDER BY fan.id) AS fan_names,
  array_agg(DISTINCT fan.id ORDER BY fan.id) AS fan_ids,
  array_agg(book.title ORDER BY book.id) AS book_titles,
  array_agg(DISTINCT book.id ORDER BY book.id) AS book_ids
 FROM
  author JOIN book on author.id=book.author_id JOIN fan ON fan.book_id=book.id
GROUP BY author.id;
```

And this is what I get

```
    author_name     | author_id |        fan_names        |  fan_ids  |                                     book_titles                                      | book_ids
--------------------+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------
 Johnathan Williams |         2 | {Alex,Alex}             | {1,7}     | {"Fairy tales","Fairy tales"}                                                        | {1}
 Lewis Carroll      |         3 | {Alice,James,Mary,Mary} | {2,4,6,8} | {"Alice in Wonderland","Alice in Wonderland","Alice in Wonderland","The final book"} | {2,4}
 Guy Fox            |         4 | {Jimmy,Nate}            | {3,5}     | {"Some other book","Some other book"}                                                | {3}
```

Naturally, there are duplicates in the book list because of the join with fans which multiplies the rows. I need to get rid of the "artificial" duplicates, but I can't simply `array_agg(DISTINCT)`, because, as you can see, one author has published multiple books with the same title  - and I need to keep that information. (I know authors aren't supposed to do that, but this is just a model!)

I found two ways of solving this:

1. The first way that comes to mind is to do this via nested request + separate join/aggregation of fans. I would like to avoid nested queries to whole tables as it slows things down significantly with extra joins.
2. The other way, sort of obvious and rather ugly, is I can load all the duplicates anyway - and do the filtering programmatically in the language I'm sending requests from (e.g., I have 5 ids, 20 names - just choose every 4th name) - but that looks very wrong and I feel like a good solution is so close but I just can't see it.

On top of the general unattractiveness of the above solutions, in the more complex case, there are more than just two joins - so the number of duplicates can grow to hundreds and the number of nested queries to ~10-15. Even if I would allow a bit of ugliness in this simple case - it becomes very costly in the real case - especially if I need to add extra joins later on.

Is there a simple solution I'm missing? It feels like I'm looking for something among the lines of `array_agg(DISTINCT ON (fan.id) fan.name)`, which, of course, doesn't work because it's not valid SQL.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: I don't get this:  "one author has published multiple books with the same name".  If you don't want duplicates, then the titles shouldn't be duplicated.  You won't be able to tell which is which anyway.

Comment: I will be able to tell which title relates to which id. In my case, the book has, say, # of pages, and i need to match the # of pages to the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want using lateral joins . . . although I don't think it makes sense:

```
 SELECT a.author_name, a.id AS author_id,
        f.fan_names, f.fan_ids, b.book_titles, b.book_ids
FROM author a CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (SELCT ARRAY_AGG(b.title ORDER BY b.id) as book_titles,
            ARRAY_AGG(b.id ORDER BY b.id) as book_ids
      FROM book b
      WHERE a.id = b.author_id
     ) b CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(f.name ORDER BY f.id) as fan_names,
             ARRAY_AGG(f.id ORDER BY f.id) as fan_ids
      FROM fan f
      WHERE f.book_id = b.id
     ) f;
```